# Struggling creating a basic list report in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, automation, ssrs-2012

I have a stored procedure I need to automate that looks at each company id in my dataset and outputs one csv for each id.

Right now I am trying to figure out how to create a basic list report in SSRS, then create a data driven subscription that cycles through all company ids - then outputs CSVs to a shared folder.

I am completely new to SSRS and have been Googling, but so far no results. I was wondering if anyone knew of any good pointers or resources to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

What version of SSRS are you using. You also need to create list report first and then you can do data driven subscription.

Here are few articles that might help you.

http://knowlton-group.com/creating-data-driven-ssrs-subscriptions/

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/data-driven-subscription-in-ssrs-2008-r2.html

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwjZ3fHGrP3NAhVJNj4KHYhBD-UQFghHMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.commongroundsolutions.net%2FSSRS_DataDrivenSubscriptions_Methodology.pptx&usg=AFQjCNHgrYfJn_u_YlQDgZo4rAPOwzombQ&sig2=5flvqG-sItnoQaLsRwmh9w&bvm=bv.127178174,d.cWw&cad=rja

https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/10969/Data-Driven-Subscription-using-SSRS-2012.html

Comment: I'm using 2012. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to create list reports. Thank you for the articles.